# AutoCompleteTextView only with items in adapter

Tags: android, autocomplete

I am in a scenario where AutoCompleteTextView should allow text only from the items present in its adapter.

I tried with spinner, but selecting items from spinner with huge list is annoying. So thought of having AutoCompleteTextView style.

Can anyone suggest a solution...

For example:
If my adapter contains 
1
2
3
11
21
31

User should able to enter only enter the items present
Mean 
it u type 1, auto complete will show 1,11. 
so user should not able to enter rather than 1, 11 in above situation.

Thanks

Comment: You mean you want to filter your data which are already present in your adapter ?

Comment: You can use `filter` for `AutoCompleteTextView` inside the adapter!

Comment: @Piyush, already AutoCompleteTextView will show filtered items as we type. But should restrict for available entries. Update my question with elaborated example.

Comment: you can't restrict user from entering data other then from your list. what you can do is put validation on button click that entered value in `AutoCompleteTextView` is from list or not.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at some of the cool apps in Play store where autocomplete is implemented, they usually take you to a new screen or activity and show the options in the listView. You can use the filter option in such cases. You can create a custom filter by overriding the getfilter() method as well.

check out the link [here](https://akshaymukadam.wordpress.com/2015/02/01/how-to-create-autocompletetextview-using-custom-filter-implementation/) for an example of custom filters implementation.

You can also some out of the box gradle libraries and add it as a module dependency in your project as well:

1. [autocompleteview](https://github.com/codetoart/autocompleteview)
2. [TokenAutoComplete](https://github.com/splitwise/TokenAutoComplete)
3. [AutoCompleteTextView](https://github.com/RacZo/Smarty-Streets-AutoCompleteTextView)

These dependencies also have some extra cool features as well.
I hope this was helpful to you.

Comment: Good resources, but i need to know the approach instead of using a 3dr party library